# Why do bold links syntax in comments work differently than answer text box?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks

While commenting on a question, I entered a hyperlink within the comment text box and tried to make it bold using the syntax that I have always seen in the answer text box. One of the scenarios didn't work. Please find the details below.

*Section #**1**:* Entered the double asterisk around the link text in the comment text box.

*Section #**2**:* The asterisks rendered as part of the comments text without making the text bold.

*Section #**3**:* Entered the double asterisk around the link text as well as the URL in the comment text box.

*Section #**4**:* Surrounding both the link text and the url worked as I expected it to work.

*Section #**5**:* However, in the Answer text box both the above mentioned inputs work correctly.

Is this a bug or is it working by design?

[image: Comment_text_box_link_bold_issue]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rules for bold and italic are stricter in comments; this is by design to prevent false positives.

Remember that comments are a stricter subset of markdown, what we call "mini-markdown". See

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score 5):

These two have been behaving identically ever since I made [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118766/115866).