# Reason for comment not rendering as expected

Tags: support, comments, markdown

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Small **bold** parser error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49120/small-bold-parser-error)
>   [Why do bold links syntax in comments work differently than answer text box?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99097/why-do-bold-links-syntax-in-comments-work-differently-than-answer-text-box)

```
As you have said  *...**it works fine**. I want to **improve** it so it could also deal with sub-entities.* this belongs in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/
```

In a comment (see below) this doesn't work. The first bold markup and the overall italics seems to be ignored. Inserting a space before the first ** works.

Why does the renderer do this?
Is there some rule i'm not following?

Comment: As you have said  *...**it works fine**. I want to **improve** it so it could also deal with sub-entities.* this belongs in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As you have said  *... **it works fine**. I want to **improve** it so it could also deal with sub-entities.* this belongs in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: First comment without space, second comment with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Small **bold** parser error](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49120/small-bold-parser-error), [Why do bold links syntax in comments work differently than answer text box?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99097/why-do-bold-links-syntax-in-comments-work-differently-than-answer-text-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99097/why-do-bold-links-syntax-in-comments-work-differently-than-answer-text-box) about the functioning of markdown in comments, Jeff mentioned the following:

> The rules for bold and italic are stricter in comments; this is by design to prevent false positives.
>
> Remember that comments are a stricter subset of markdown, what we call "mini-markdown". See
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: I've read the help on comment formatting, i couldn't find anywhere where it mentions having to leave a space before nested bold markup.

Comment: @George: Does this link help? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49120/small-bold-parser-error

Comment: Yeah, that looks like pretty much the same issue as mine, although i'm not totally happy with the answer. Thanks.